# How can I install the app written in Flutter in iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to install the flutter app on the ios system ,how can I do it ?

Comment: Did you encounter any problems with this howto: https://flutter.io/setup/#ios-setup

Answer (score 8):

The `flutter` tool knows how to install and run applications on iOS and Android (by calling out to Xcode or Android Studio tools under the covers).

Flutter has instructions on setting up your machine for iOS and Android development including adding the `flutter` tool to your $PATH:
https://flutter.io/setup/

There are also instructions walking you through creating and running your first Flutter app:
https://flutter.io/getting-started/

`flutter run --release` is probably the command you're looking for, as that will install and run the .app on an attached device (iOS or Android).

In the case of iOS, sometimes there are signing failures, or configuration errors specific to your machine/account which the `flutter` tool can't fix for you and it will direct you to open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` in your Flutter app directory and make modifications inside XCode (or use the build/run buttons there).

"Flutter apps" are just normal iOS and Android apps which use a FlutterView (which itself is a normal UIView subclass on iOS and android.View subclass on Android), thus normal iOS and Android development instructions, particularly when pertaining to putting an App on the device generally apply.

Answer (score 0):

For installing/Setup the flutter in iOS is easy.
Installing the flutter in iOS Have simple steps

1. First [download the Flutter](https://flutter.io/sdk-archive/#macos) latest SDK from flutter official website or clone the flutter repository from [flutter GitHub Repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter).
2. Setup the flutter folder path globally

   ```
    export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Run the Flutter Doctor command For checking all the dependencies is complete or not.
4. Download the vistual studio.
5. Install the XCode
6. Attach the Flutter SDK with vistual studio.

You can also See this link for [Install the flutter in Mac OS](https://developerfly.com/how-to-install-flutter-flutter-tutorial/)