# Install flutter app developed using android studio on iphone

Tags: flutter

I have recently started developing an application with flutter using a plugin with android studio on windows 10. I was able to run app on android phone by connecting a phone with usb debugging mode. What are the steps to run the flutter app on my iphone? I have never built an app before for ios. Any stepwise guide will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess that has to be done using Xcode.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can not run a flutter app on iOS if your development host is
Windows. Like [Zeeshan Shabbir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5275639/zeeshan-shabbir) said, you have to use XCode and
therefore you need a MacOS system.

If you do not have a Mac you can use a virtual machine (for example
with High Sierra) inside your Windows host and install XCode + Flutter
to run the app on your IPhone. You have to be a Apple Developer to do
this, but the free membership is enough I think.

Details can be found here: [https://techsviewer.com/](https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-high-sierra-virtualbox-windows/)

To install flutter on the virtual machine just follow the instructions
from the [flutter-website](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/).

Answer (score 2):

> The flutter tool knows how to install and run applications on iOS and
>   Android (by calling out to Xcode or Android Studio tools under the
>   covers).
>
> Flutter has instructions on setting up your machine for iOS and
>   Android development including adding the flutter tool to your $PATH:
>   https://flutter.io/setup/
>
> There are also instructions walking you through creating and running
>   your first Flutter app: https://flutter.io/getting-started/
>
> flutter run --release is probably the command you're looking for, as
>   that will install and run the .app on an attached device (iOS or
>   Android).
>
> In the case of iOS, sometimes there are signing failures, or
>   configuration errors specific to your machine/account which the
>   flutter tool can't fix for you and it will direct you to open
>   ios/Runner.xcworkspace in your Flutter app directory and make
>   modifications inside XCode (or use the build/run buttons there).
>
> "Flutter apps" are just normal iOS and Android apps which use a
>   FlutterView (which itself is a normal UIView subclass on iOS and
>   android.View subclass on Android), thus normal iOS and Android
>   development instructions, particularly when pertaining to putting an
>   App on the device generally apply.

This was answered by [Eric Seidel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42582298/5275639)

Comment: I have checked this answer. But as per the links mentioned no specific commands or explanation is given for running app on iphone. The commands can only run app on android phones. The release command runs an application in release mode not in debug mode.

Comment: @DhirajDevkar You would need Xcode to run app on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Mac System with Xcode for running a build to the iPhone. Follow this link to set up your mac for running a flutter build to iPhone. 
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos