# How do I add iPhone to Android Studio?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter

How do I add iPhone to Android Studio? AVD manager has only Android and no iOS. Do I have to install Xcode for that? Picture below is from flutters guide:

[image]

https://flutter.io/using-ide/

Comment: Yes, you have to install Xcode, it comes with an iOS simulator.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, and I need a Mac for that, right?

Comment: Yes, no way around that.

Comment: Thank you for your replies!

Comment: You need macos and not a physical one. There are several providers who offer cloud hosted macs who are good for compiling and uploading to the app store.

Comment: some more details in the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001690/install-flutter-app-developed-using-android-studio-on-iphone

Comment: Do you want to use a physical iPhone or an emulator/simulator?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to install [Xcode from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), which will only run on macOS. There you have a simulator for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

To add iPhone to Android Studio, You need one physical macbook in which you have to install Xcode & Xcode Command Line Tools along with simulator.

To Publish iOS Flutter APP, you may not needed macbook, one can use [codemagic](https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml-quick-start/building-a-flutter-app/). It is very usefull. You can use Android Studio as IDE for Pod &  plist files setting and other XML editing.

Answer (score 0):

Others have submitted good answers, but I think I can add some value.

How to add an iPhone to Android Studio? : I simply connect an iPhone to my mac (mini) via a cable (USB A on one end and whatever you call it on the iPhone end) and it shows up in the Target selector (the app tooltip is "Flutter Device Selection")

But ... maybe you want a simulator/emulator instead of using a physical device. Other answers cover that. TL;DR: install Xcode.

Do I need to install Xcode? : From Flutter docs:

> To develop Flutter apps for iOS, you need a Mac with Xcode installed.

FYI/FWIW: You can only build and debug for iOS on a mac. You can also build/debug Android on mac. But, on Windows, you can only do Android.

Answer (score -1):

In Android Studio, choose Open iOS Simulator from the device pulldown.  This should launch the Simulator.  Then go to the Simulator's File menu and choose Open Simulator, which will let you choose any additional model of iPhone or iPad you'd like to test. (If the model you want is not listed, choose File -> New Simulator to add it.) In the File -> Open Simulator menu, a checkmark will appear to the left of every model you've chosen to simulate.  Each model you've chosen will then automatically show up as an option in the device pulldown of Android Studio.  Finally run your app from Android Studio using the device pulldown to select the iOS device of your choice.