# iPhone is not detected in Flutter Android Studio though "flutter devices" command shows

Tags: android-studio, flutter

`$ flutter devices` shows following result.

```
$ flutter devices
1 connected device:

my_iPhone • <UDID> • ios • iOS 12.3.1
```

However, Android Studio does not detect this iphone.
Android Studio GUI shows .
May I know how to fix it ???

`$ flutter doctor` shows No issues.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51240570/3266152) stating that you can't do it through Android Studio. You need to run it through e.g., xCode, IntelliJ, or run it from the terminal (`flutter run`)

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know Android Studio cannot connect iphone real device. I am able to find it in VSCode. Only Android Studio is not available ?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if it is related but sharing with the thread.

Keep the iphone connected to mac and run
*"flutter devices"* command

You will get following error if *Developer Mode* is OFF

*• Error: To use Your iPhone for development, enable Developer Mode in Settings → Privacy & Security.  (code 6)*

Answer (score 5):

Steps to Reproduce

1. Connect iPhone to MacBook, Removed the cable, lock the phone, reinserted the cable, and then unlocked the device. The device may showed up in Android Studio.(Preferred USB-C to Lightning cable - not compulsory).
2. Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio.
3. Unlock device whilst it's connected.
4. All above failes Restarting iPhone & MacBook.

Comment: I removed the cable, locked the phone, reinserted the cable, and then unlocked the device. The device showed up in AS.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar I tried your way before proceeding to Invalidate Caches because that is time consuming. And it worked. You should add this as an answer.

Comment: TayyabMazhar and beria, I haved added that in my answer. I Thank you for your improvement suggestions.

Comment: What @TayyabMazhar describe works for me...

Answer (score 5):

I found out after running command "flutter doctor -v" that xcode installation was not complete.

[image]

So, I went to https://developer.apple.com/download/ and installed the remaining and necessary profiles for ios and macos.

After installation, I run below two commands in Android studio terminal and unplug data cable of device and then plugged device again and then refresh the device list in Android studio and I get the connected iPhone.

```
    sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by restarting my PC.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable 'Developer Mode'

To enable developer mode on your iPhone:

1. Open the Settings app
2. Select the Privacy & Security option
3. Scroll down to Developer Mode and turn it on
4. Once enabled, reconnect your iPhone to your computer using a cable. Your iPhone should now appear in the device list.

Detail: https://www.telemessage.com/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-ios-16/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in that Android Studio on my Mac M1 was not seeing my iphone that was plugged in.

It turned out that Xcode had been updated and the license agreements were not agreed. To fix:

`flutter devices`   will show the issue
then
`sudo xcodebuild -license`
will resolve it.

Hope this will help someone here!

Answer (score 0):

Try to first run your App directly on Xcode (without Android Studio)

On Xcode open the `ios` subfolder of your project only

If you find a message like the image bellow when trying to select the device, you may need to update your Xcode and/or your iOS device

To be able to update the Xcode, you may need to update your Mac as well

[image: xcode]